# Cuando usamos las interfaces comparable o comparator, ¿por que tenemos que hacer compatible con el método equals y como hacerlo?

Tags: java

Aparentemente me funciona bien, pero en la información que me he leido me recomienda que el método `compareTo()` definido por la interfaz `Comparable()` sea compatible con el método `equals()`.
Esto quiere decir que:
`objeto1.compareTo(objeto2)==0` cuando `objeto1.equals(objeto2)==true`.

No se exactamente que tengo que hacer pero sin hacer ningún `equals` me funciona.

tengo este metodo para llamarlo:

```
public void ordenarPorNombreComparableComparator() {
    Collections.sort(listaEmpleados);
    listarTodo();
}
```

Clase:

```
package conArrayList_Vector_Comparable_comparator;  
    public abstract class Empleado implements Comparable<Empleado>{
        static int autonumerico;
        private String nombre;
        private int edad;
        private double sueldo;
        private String codigo;

        public Empleado() {
            autonumerico++;
            this.nombre = "Empleado"+autonumerico;
            this.edad =(int)(Math.random()*50+20);
            this.sueldo =1000; //Math.random()*1000+1000;
            this.codigo = generadorCodigo();
            //this.codigo = "z"+autonumerico;
        }

        public abstract String generadorCodigo();

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public int getEdad() {
            return edad;
        }

        public void setEdad(int edad) {
            this.edad = edad;
        }

        public double getSueldo() {
            return sueldo;
        }

        public void setSueldo(double sueldo) {
            this.sueldo = sueldo;
        }

        public String getCodigo() {
            return codigo;
        }

        public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Empleado [nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + ", sueldo=" + sueldo + ", codigo=" + codigo + "]";
        }

        @Override//ordenNatural
        public int compareTo(Empleado o) {//Comparamos por codigo

            return this.codigo.compareToIgnoreCase(o.codigo);   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La documentación recomienda (es decir, no es obligatorio pero es una buena práctica) que los objetos comparables tengan cierta consistencia: no tiene sentido que dos objetos que `valen igual` (uno no es mayor que el otro), no seanconsiderados *iguales*.

Te pongo un ejemplo con números, para que veas a qué se refiere:

Imagina que tenemos una lista de números:

```
List<Integer> numeros= ....
```

Y la queremos ordenar. Puesto que Integer es una clase que implementa Comparable, `numeros.sort()` funcionará sin problemas.

Ahora queremos encontrar los números repetidos. Si hemos ordenado la lista, esperamos que los números repetidos estén juntos, con lo que no tendríamos que comprobar para cada número todas las demás posiciones:

```
{ 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7}  //si el que está a su lado no es igual, es que no hay repetidos.
```

Para comprobar que dos números son iguales, debería dar igual que usásemos equals o compareTo:

```
Integer cinco=5;
Integer otroNum = ...;
boolean b = cinco.equals(otroNum) == (cinco.compareTo(otroNum) == 0);
//Si b no es true SIEMPRE, tenemos una inconsistencia!
```

Y, como bonus extra, sería deseable que si dos objetos se consideran iguales usando estos dos métodos, la llamada a `hashCode()` en ambos objetos devolviera el mismo resultado, porque de ese modo las tablas hash los asignarían a la misma posición, ayudando a encontrar repeticiones.

Pero como he comentado al inicio, esto no es siempre necesario: podríamos encontrarnos casos en los que dos objetos tengan un mismo *peso* pero no sean iguales: si queremos ordenar una lista de personas por su nombre alfabéticamente, tendremos un orden, pero que dos personas se llamen igual no quiere decir que sean la misma persona.

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo entendí.Gracias.